# Sending a conditional variable based on previous range of response data in jmeter

Tags: variables, jmeter

I'm trying to do a POST request test loop and set a particular variable in the  request that is based on results of previous responses (specifically the last 200). For instance, if X appears 5 times in the last 200 responses, the variable = 2. If X appears 10 times in the last 200 responses, the variable = 6, and so on. I've already extracted the X value with RegEx extractor and have it exported to a CSV data file, if that helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CSV file with 5 or 10 (or whatever number) lines of `X` and want to conditionally set another variable value I would suggest going for the [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with the code like:

```
def entries = 0

new File("/path/to/your/file.csv").eachLine {
    entries++
}

switch (entries) {
    case 5:
        vars.put("myVar", "2")
        break;
    case 10:
        vars.put("myVar", "6")
        break;
    //etc.
    default:
        vars.put("myVar", "0")
}
```

It will count the number of lines in the csv file and set `${myVar}` variable value based on it.

- `vars` stand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides programmatic read/write access to the JMeter Variables
- [File.eachLine()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachLine(groovy.lang.Closure)) is a Groovy enhancement over normal JDK File class
- [switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement should be self-explanatory

See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guile for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.